# How to get the post data without form builder

Tags: php, symfony

Normally I am using formbuilder to get the post data from form.

However,now I need very simple form not relevant with entity.

I can get the method like this and

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {/
```

I want to get the each form data.(name is form name)

```
echo($this->getRequest()->get('name')->getData());
```

it shows error.

I used to use formbuilder and bindRequet normally to pick the data from form object.

How can I get the each form data from this->getRequest() without using formbuilder?

Comment: whitebear please investigate a bit yourself before asking these kind of questions :) There is a highly upvoted answer with 60k+ views ... for me it's the second! result returned by a simple "symfony post request" google search. I'm pretty sure you could've found that one faster than asking this question.

Comment: Sorry,I dodn't understand which way I should investigate,I will be carefully check the post log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get it from the `request` property:

```
$this->getRequest()->request->get('foo');
```